# python List files with spaces

Tags: python, for-loop, logging, md5, spaces

I have the following code:

Basically is to pull md5 from each file. The problem is with the files that has spaces , what would be the solution to the program can take into account those files and not skip them.

```
def onepath(archivo):
        logging.basicConfig(filename=salida,filemode="w", format='%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
        for filename in (file for file in os.listdir(archivo)):
                with open(filename) as checkfile:
                        logging.info("MD5 " + "(%s) = " % filename + hashlib.md5(checkfile.read()).hexdigest())
```

I was reading about the method shlex, but not sure how can I implement.

Can you help me?

---

I think that files with spaces are showing. I did a short snippet not im facing a problem that I cant have control in how Linux understand the spaces on the filenames in order to do as follows:

```html
files_destino = [f for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(sys.argv[1].strip()))]
for i in files_destino:
                print i
                subprocess.call(["cp","-v", "%s" % i,"/tmp/"])
```

In the shell shows:

```html
bash-3.2$ ./comodin.py ./espacio/
Boxx view.pdf
cp: Boxx view.pdf: No such file or directory
hola.txt
hola.txt -> /tmp/hola.txt
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Why is "spaces" in quotes?

Comment: Sorry. Writing issues here :)

Comment: Do you mean files containing the U+0020 character? Why would that matter?

Comment: Inside a folder there are a sequence of files e.g. "user manual_v1.pdf","user manual_v2.pdf"  . Need to pull their md5. So when  the line "....for filename in (file for file in os.listdir(archivo)):...." takes "user" and "manual_v1.pdf", "user","manual_v2.pdf" as four different files when only exists 2 files. I hope I have explained better.

Comment: *file* is a pre defined file type object, you may want to rename the file variable to something else. It creates confusion when reading. Also, os.listdir output is a list is there a reason for reiterating again?

Answer (score 0):

```
def onepath(archivo):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=salida,filemode="w", format='%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
    for filename in os.listdir(archivo):
        filepath = os.path.join(archivo, filename)
        with open(filepath) as checkfile:
            logging.info("MD5 " + "(%s) = " % filename + hashlib.md5(checkfile.read()).hexdigest())
```

Comment: Thanks @Rain Lee it gave an idea but still with the drawback.

Comment: To copy files, you should use shutil.copy(src, dst) instead of using subprocess with system command "cp". Similarly, src, dst can be prepared with os.path.join(sys.argv[1], filename)

Comment: I will work. But "cp" this was an example here to point out to handle filenames with spaces (As Unix requieres files with slashes in front the spaces. The intention is to substitute "cp" for the line "hashlib.md5(checkfile.read()).hexdigest())" to pull the MD5s.

Comment: Why do you want to mix pure python code with system utils? If you prefer to do it with system command such as "md5sum" or "cp", you can do it as following: ls | xargs -I{} md5sum "{}"

Comment: It could be that easy or even better with a GUI program. But why not trying in python & learn?

Comment: My point is: if you want to try in python, you better write pure python code, combining different things in this way is ugly and is just a hack to make things work

Comment: Programming is subjective.